# PHP rendering JS useless

Tags: php, javascript

Ok, so, I'm not at all familiar with PHP dev, however, here I find myself. I have a page I created in HTML/CSS and JS that works great with several JS plugins. However, when I turn it into a php page, the JS is conflicting and rendered useless.

It is because the PHP is aggregating it into one large js file. When I run it in debug and loading up all the files separately everything is fine. Has anyone hit this before?

Here is how I am loading them:

```
register_script( array(

    'base_path' =>  PROJECTURL,
    'scripts'    => array(
        'js/libs/jquery-1.5.min.js',
        'js/libs/jquery.jscrollpane.js',
        'js/libs/jquery.selectbox-0.6.1.js',
        'js/libs/jquery.mousewheel.js',
            'js/libs/jquery.autocomplete.min.js',
        'js/libs/jquery.watermark.js', 
                'js/propriatary-name.js',

    )

) );
```

Comment: Are you working with some sort of PHP framework? You're gonna have to tell us where register_script() comes from and what it does...

Comment: If PHP's mungeing the script somehow, you'd most likely get errors logged in the browser's error console - in FF hit shift-ctrl-J to bring that up and see if anything's produced when you load one of the "bad" pages.

Comment: as well as telling us what `register_script` does, you'll need to elaborate on "JS is conflicting and rendered useless". So the errors are....?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your register_script function is doing what you expect. This is not a standard PHP function, so unless you are using a framework, you need to change some things.

Your PHP gets executed server side, while your .js files are inluded in the DOM on the client side. If you're doing this programatically, just add your scripts to an array, then add the scripts to your HTML output with a foreach loop:

```
$pagescripts = array(
        'js/libs/jquery-1.5.min.js',
        'js/libs/jquery.jscrollpane.js',
        'js/libs/jquery.selectbox-0.6.1.js',
        'js/libs/jquery.mousewheel.js',
        'js/libs/jquery.autocomplete.min.js',
        'js/libs/jquery.watermark.js', 
        'js/propriatary-name.js');

foreach($pagescripts[$page] as $v){
    $output .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" . $v . "\"></script>\n";
}
```